# is it possible to check weather the given email id has access to google drive or not for php web application

Tags: php, google-drive-api

For php web application using google drive api
Is it possible to check weather the given email id has access to google drive or not ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions

Comment: Actually I want to check whether the user has a google drive account or not?